# ios:Bring Child view to Front view in tabbarcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I am writing an application with help screens. As per my requirement I need to show the help screens when the view appears for the first time and I am placing the code on the tabbar controller class as `(void)viewDidLoad`:

```
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    XDKWalkthroughController *sc = [[XDKWalkthroughController alloc]  
     initWithView:self.view];
    [self addChildViewController:sc];
    [self.view addSubview:sc.view];
    sc.delegate = self;
    [sc start];
}
```

When I am placing this code I am getting one more tabbar item along with existing tabbar item. How to avoid that in my case?

And same thing when I placed in the first view i.e in the first tab view controller view did class. Both navigation bar and tabbar are pushing the child view back.

I have tried these two scenarios, please help me with the possible solution.

Comment: you have to do the whole thing in appdelegate it self...if you are launching for the first time load XDKWalkthroughController, or else load tabbar controller...you can do this if you are using xibs, I dont know how to do this using storyboards as I am very beginer to it.

Comment: add it into window..

Comment: can u expain with code